# PHP define array: PHP or server config issue?

Tags: php, arrays, config

Myself and another (remote) developer are experiencing different behaviour with the same following PHP code:

```
define("URL", array(

    "services" => array(
        "orderCreate" => 'api/createOrder.php',
        "orderGet" => 'api/getOrderDetails.php',
        "orderPatch" => 'api/patchOrder.php',
        "orderCapture" => 'api/captureOrder.php'
    ),

    "redirectUrls" => array(
        "returnUrl" => 'pages/success.php',
        "cancelUrl" => 'pages/cancel.php',
    )
));

echo "order create var is: ".URL['services']['orderCreate']."<BR>";
```

My result is: "U"

The other developer's result is, correctly, "api/createOrder.php".

The "U" result I am seeing is being populated by the "U" of "URL".

My PHP version: 7.4.30

Remote developer's PHP version: 7.4.26

Does anybody know why this would be? Something at a PHP version level, some difference in config on our own web servers, or something else?

ENTIRE FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
Cache-Control:public;
>

<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<TITLE>Hello world
</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>


CODE:<BR>

<pre>

define("URL", array(

    "services" => array(
        "orderCreate" => 'api/createOrder.php',
        "orderGet" => 'api/getOrderDetails.php',
        "orderPatch" => 'api/patchOrder.php',
        "orderCapture" => 'api/captureOrder.php'
    ),

    "redirectUrls" => array(
        "returnUrl" => 'pages/success.php',
        "cancelUrl" => 'pages/cancel.php',
    )
));

echo "order create var is: ".URL['services']['orderCreate'];
</pre>



<?php

define("URL", array(

    "services" => array(
        "orderCreate" => 'api/createOrder.php',
        "orderGet" => 'api/getOrderDetails.php',
        "orderPatch" => 'api/patchOrder.php',
        "orderCapture" => 'api/captureOrder.php'
    ),

    "redirectUrls" => array(
        "returnUrl" => 'pages/success.php',
        "cancelUrl" => 'pages/cancel.php',
    )
));
?>

<BR><BR>
OUTPUT:<BR><BR>

<?php

echo "order create var is: ".URL['services']['orderCreate'];
// echo "order create var is: ",URL['services']['orderCreate'];
// same result
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Are there any notices, warnings or errors? I can't explain or reproduce the `U` result otherwise - if the `URL` constant was somehow not defined, PHP 7 should warn "Use of undefined constant", "Illegal string offset", "Illegal string offset".

Comment: Thanks Wander for the quick response. I've got the Developer Tools Console open and it's completely clean, showing no errors or warnings. So are you saying you get the desired response of "api/createOrder.php"?

Comment: Make sure you check the server error logs and also view the source in the browser. PHP errors will not show up in the browser's Developer Tools console.

Comment: `$url` is not defined.  https://3v4l.org/qJvC5 Where is your output? Console or browser?

Comment: Thanks Markus. I should have removed the ref to $url (which I've now edited out). The behaviour is the same regardless. The output is to the browser. The server error logs appear to be clean. So I can see on your link that the output is as expected, so I'm completely stumped as to why it's resolving to "U" seemingly only for me on multiple browsers.

Comment: Is this the complete file or is there anything else which may break it? View the browsers Source with CTRL+U. Does it show `order create var is: `? Paste the whole file into another editor like notepad, and copy back to your IDE. This will remove any hidden whitespaces.

Comment: That is the complete file with the exception of HTML, HEAD, TITLE and BODY tags. The browser source displays: 
order create var is: U

Comment: Have enhanced the question to include the original file. I've also tested it on a another domain (to rule out anything quirky on the original domain) albeit another domain on the same web server with the same unexpected output of simply "U"

Comment: Can you reboot the server? Maybe any opcache is involved. Try `echo "order create var is: ", URL['services']['orderCreate'], "<BR>";` (comma instead dot)

Comment: Although not related to your problem, `Cache-Control:public` in the `DOCTYPE` is not correct.

Comment: Thanks Markus & Chris. It's a live web server so a reboot is not something that can easily be done. I've removed the Cache-Control (just for cleanlinless) and replaced the dot appends with a comma per your advice Markus, but with the same result. I forced the browser to refresh to avoid at least any browser caching issues. I cannot for the life of me understand why it would output a "U" for me and the correct variable for everybody else!

Comment: So strange. Can you SSH to it and run from cli? A reboot should be no big deal! You could just restart apache with `sudo service apache2 graceful`.

Comment: @Steve Do you somehow have zero-width characters in your script?  How did you create the file on your end?  Did you copy-paste part of the script from another source?  What happens if you remove all of the "erroneous" php scripting, then manually type the same text into your file and save?  In the absence of a reproducible example, we're going to have to close this question as off-topic: no-repro.

Comment: Have you both got the same version of PHP running ?  Because Define only works with arrays on PHP 7+

Comment: With the full code you have shown, https://3v4l.org/4ZYh7 gets the same correct result across all PHP versions supported there. Can you try and write this to a file instead, something like `file_put_contents('foo.txt', URL['services']['orderCreate']);`- and then check what that file contains via FTP or console? Exclude the possibility that anything perhaps "filters" your PHP script output, before it gets passed on to the client.

Comment: Thank-you all for the comments. That original snippet of code was downloaded from an official example PayPal demo, so I'm going to try manually typing it into a clean Notepad and uploading to the web server. I too get the correct behaviour on Eval, just not on my live web server! Will report back shortly.

Comment: I was asking that in comment #6. :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like we've figured this out. Although cPanel was showing the server as running PHP 7.4.30, for some reason in MultiPHP Manager the domain was configured to run PHP 5.6. Equally this odd behaviour is backed up by Eval parsing the code with v5.6: https://3v4l.org/vfTgF#v5.6.0. At least if any of us see it again this thread may help others.